# How can I iterate through string bytes numerically?

Tags: c++, utf-8, windows-1256

I have a string encoded in `windows-1256` and is displayed as `ÓíÞÑÕäí áßí ¿`.
The string should be displayed in Arabic if the operating system is configured to use the encoding.

Here is the HEX representation of the string:

[image: Hex representation]

My intention is to convert the text to `utf8` manually (using lookup tables to see which bytes need to be altered, and which should be left as-is).

I will need to iterate through all bytes in the string to see the binary value of the byte.
The string is printed to the output stream as `ÓíÞÑÕäí áßí ¿`. The string length is 13 visible characters. But when I try to iterate through the bytes, the loop is run double the size (24) iterations. Maybe it wrongly assumes at UTF8 or UTF16.

How can I access the numerical value of each byte in the string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main() {

    string myString = "ÓíÞÑÕäí áßí ¿";  
    // text is written in Windows-1256 encoding

    cout << "string is : " << myString << endl;  
    // outputs: string is : ÓíÞÑÕäí áßí ¿

    cout << "length : " << myString.size() << endl;  
   // outputs : length : 24
    
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < myString.size(); ++i)
    {
        uint8_t         b1 = (uint8_t)myString.c_str()[i];
        unsigned char   b2 = (unsigned char) myString.c_str()[i];
        unsigned int    b3 = (unsigned int) myString.c_str()[i];
        int             b4 = (int) myString.c_str()[i];

        cout    << i << " - " 
                << std::bitset<8>(myString.c_str()[i]) 
                << " : " << b1   // prints �
                << " : " << b2   // prints �
                << " : " << b3   // prints very large numbers, except for spaces (32)
                << " : " << b4   // negative values, except for the space (32)
                << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## output

```
string is : ÓíÞÑÕäí áßí ¿
length : 24

 0 - 11000011 : � : � : 4294967235 : -61
 1 - 10010011 : � : � : 4294967187 : -109
 2 - 11000011 : � : � : 4294967235 : -61
 3 - 10101101 : � : � : 4294967213 : -83
 4 - 11000011 : � : � : 4294967235 : -61
 5 - 10011110 : � : � : 4294967198 : -98
 6 - 11000011 : � : � : 4294967235 : -61
 7 - 10010001 : � : � : 4294967185 : -111
 8 - 11000011 : � : � : 4294967235 : -61
 9 - 10010101 : � : � : 4294967189 : -107
10 - 11000011 : � : � : 4294967235 : -61
11 - 10100100 : � : � : 4294967204 : -92
12 - 11000011 : � : � : 4294967235 : -61
13 - 10101101 : � : � : 4294967213 : -83
14 - 00100000 :   :   : 32 : 32
15 - 11000011 : � : � : 4294967235 : -61
16 - 10100001 : � : � : 4294967201 : -95
17 - 11000011 : � : � : 4294967235 : -61
18 - 10011111 : � : � : 4294967199 : -97
19 - 11000011 : � : � : 4294967235 : -61
20 - 10101101 : � : � : 4294967213 : -83
21 - 00100000 :   :   : 32 : 32
22 - 11000010 : � : � : 4294967234 : -62
23 - 10111111 : � : � : 4294967231 : -65
```

Comment: `uint8_t` is probably a typedef for `unsigned char`, and casting a `char` which is signed 8 bit integer to unsigned integer can indeed produce very large numbers. Try to print the values as signed ints.

Comment: @pptaszni I already tried signed integer. It printed the wrong values

Comment: Post text, not images of text so we can copy the byte data if needed, and the byte data is actually UTF-8 for `'ÓíÞÑÕäí áßí ¿'`.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'سيقرصني لكي ؟'.encode('cp1256').decode('cp1252')` returns mojibake  `'ÓíÞÑÕäí áßí ¿'` and vice versa:  `'ÓíÞÑÕäí áßí ¿'.encode('cp1252').decode('cp1256')` -> `سيقرصني لكي ؟`…ˇ

Comment: Your source code is saved as UTF-8, so your string contains UTF-8-encoded `'ÓíÞÑÕäí áßí ¿'`.  That's why the length is 24.  You'd have to save your source in Windows-1256 and convince your compiler that is the source encoding for your string to be encoded in Windows-1256.

Comment: @JosefZ how can I convert the text from windows1256 to utf8 in c++?

Comment: Your source code is saved as UTF-8, so why don't you use `string myString = "سيقرصني لكي ؟"`? To display it properly, use appropriate code page in `chcp` _before_ you launch your exe…

Comment: @JosefZ never mind. I was able to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to iterate through the string byte by byte using the following code, (which I copied from another answer, but couldn't find the link to it)

```
// this function receives any std::string 
// and returns a vector<byte> containing the numerical value of each byte in the string
vector<byte> getBytes(string const &s) {
    std::vector<std::byte> bytes;
    bytes.reserve(std::size(s));

    std::transform(std::begin(s), 
                   std::end(s),
                   std::back_inserter(bytes), 
                   [](char const &c){ return std::byte(c);});

    return bytes;
}
```